# ImageView not display on device

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Please can anyone tell me what's wrong with my ImageView?

Here is my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="elektrasoft.com.ridehubdriver.LoginActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="here is some text "
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/input_background"
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:hint="Email ..."
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/input_background"
        android:id="@+id/passswordEditText"
        android:hint="Password ..."
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passswordEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn" />


    <Button
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:id="@+id/signupBtn"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the image showing in Android Studio
[image]

and here is the image showing on device "Galaxy S6"

[image]

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks bro , its working :)

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

to

```
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```